# Solr outer join / not join query

Tags: join, solr, left-join

I may be asking too much but I want to do a left outer join between two cores
and get data from `A` only where `B` does not have related data.

Following is exactly my equivalent SQL query (for simplicity I have removed other conditions),

```
1. SELECT  A.* FROM A AS A
WHERE A.ID NOT IN (SELECT B.A_ID FROM B AS B WHERE B.STATUS_ID != 1)
```

I understand that solr join is actually subquery, I need data from only `A`.

It would be very easy if the `not` was not there in where condition for sub query.

For example,

```
2. SELECT  A.* FROM A AS A
WHERE A.ID IN (SELECT B.A_ID FROM B AS B WHERE B.STATUS_ID != 1)
```

I can have `q={!join from=aId to=id fromIndex=b}(-statusId:1)`.

How can I do a nagete here, i.e. solr query for **`1`**

Comment: Your first query is an antijoin and your second is a semijoin; neither is an outer join (which is actually a union anyway!).

Comment: I have created the query in sql as outer join only then for converting I realized that solr does sub query so I converted outer join to subquery, So same thing can be achieved via outer join too. That's why the title outer join/ not join.